# How do you get VSCode Intellisense to work with ServiceNow Script Includes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, servicenow

So, I've been working with the ServiceNow Extension for VSCode and there have been a number of quirks but otherwise it's been working great for my purposes.
One of the issues I've run into when working with larger scoped applications, however, is that Intellisense will not find functions and other items from Script Includes outside of the one that I'm currently working on.

The standard format for a Script Include in ServiceNow is:

```js
var MyScriptInclude = Class.create();
MyScriptInclude.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {
    },
    /**
     * Do nothing function for illustration purposes
     * @param {*} a
     * @param {string} b
     * @param {number} c
     */
    fn_1: function(a, b, c) {
    },

    fn_n: function(d, e) {
    },
    
    type: 'MyScriptInclude'
};
```

So if I were to be working on the following in Visual Studio Code.
Intellisense will not pull up any information when trying to reference fn_1 from my other script include.
All it will display in the tooltip is 'any'

```js
var MyOtherScriptInclude = Class.create();
MyOtherScriptInclude.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {
    },
    
    doSomethingWithOther: function() {
        var my_first_script_include = new MyScriptInclude();

        my_first_script_include.fn_1(); //<-- does not find any information about fn_1
    },
    
    type: 'MyOtherScriptInclude'
};
```

Now I get this. VSCode has no idea what Class.create() is returning.
ServiceNow uses an out-of-the-box Script Include named PrototypeServer to 'build' any script includes you put into your scripts. This is what that looks like:

```js
var Class = {
  create: function() {
    return function() {
        /* This anonymous function will execute in the scope of the caller
           in interpreted mode. The initalize method is a utility we provide
           for giving a hook into the creation of a script include in scope.
           Many global script includes do not have an initialize function, and
           therefore we should only call this.initialize when present.
         */
        if (this.initialize)
            this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }
};
```

So that all said, I've tried a number of things to try to get Visual Studio Code to try to make the connection between the class variable and the prototype object in these Script Includes.

I've tried documenting (what I call) the class variable and using lends in the prototype. This approach correctly associates the prototype and class when compiling documentation  but, alas, does nothing for Intellisense.

```js
/**
 * My do nothing class for illustration purposes
 * @class
 */
var MyScriptInclude = Class.create();
MyScriptInclude.prototype = {
    /** @lends MyScriptInclude.prototype */
    /**
     * @constructs
     */
    initialize: function() { }
    //...
};
```

I've also tried lends outside of the prototype

```js
/** @lends MyScriptInclude.prototype */
MyScriptInclude.prototype = {};
```

I've tried defining the class variable as a function because Class.create() returns an anonymous function.

```js
/**
 * My do nothing class for illustration purposes
 * @type {function}
 */
var MyScriptInclude = Class.create();
MyScriptInclude.prototype = { };
```

I've also tried pulling the PrototypeServer global Script Include into my workspace.
VSCode will then correctly find the Class.create() function, display info about Class.create(), and interpret the class variable as a function... but there's still a disconnect between the class variable and the prototype functions and Intellisense still shows 'any' for any of the methods in the prototype, won't find definitions, etc.

This isn't a deal breaker by any means as doing development within VSCode is a heck of a lot faster than doing it within the ServiceNow instance. However, it'd sure be a lot nicer if I could figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is deceptively simple.
Assign the class variable a generic function.
Then overwrite the generic function with the result from Class.create()

```js
/**
 * My do nothing class for illustration purposes
 */
 var MyScriptInclude = function(){}; //<--
 MyScriptInclude = Class.create();
 MyScriptInclude.prototype = {
     /** @lends DataSourceInterfaceFactory.prototype */
     
     /** @constructs */
     initialize: function() {},

     type: "MyScriptInclude"
 };
```

By using this approach you maintain the out of the box functionality provided by ServiceNow's PrototypeServer no matter if it changes in the future or not and intellisense will pickup the information in this class/script include from other places in your project.

The only thing that does not work is the lends/constructs definition to specify that the constructor information should be provided from the initialize function. When you instantiate this class using new intellisense will not give you information.
But if you really wanted to you could look it up by dot walking to initialize.
I will update this answer if I find out how to link up the constructor properly. Otherwise, this is the 95% solution.